# OBTENER REGISTROS DE UNA COLUMNA EN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla en SQL SERVER

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito un query para obtener todos los datos de la columna estante, hasta ahorita solo e logrado obtener el nombre de las columnas con:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'INDICE_DOCUMENTO'
```

Comment: ehhh...lo que estas pidiendo es muy raro... estas haciendo un query a las tablas del sistema a la base de datos.. que es exactamente lo que queres, a la tabla que vos queres... o estas buscando otra cosa totalmente diferente?

Comment: Sin mayúsculas sostenidas, por favor. Eso incluye el título. Lo otro, por favor especifica a qué te refieres con _todos los datos_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estas haciendo es una consulta a las tablas del sistema. Lo que necesitas es investigar un poco de las consultas base de SQL y para tu caso, hacer la búsqueda dentro de tu esquema y tabla.

La sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
SELECT <columna_a_buscar> FROM <tabla>;
```

En tu caso quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT estante FROM INDICE_DOCUMENTO;
```

Comment: Igual explicarlo no le cae mal al OP

Comment: Igual habria que tratar de entender porque OP hizo una consulta a las tablas del sistema no?

Comment: Es exactamente lo que estaba buscando, en la tabla indice_documento existe una columna que se llama estante y con ese query obtengo los registros de esa columna.. es decir 1,10,100... Gracias!

Comment: @DanielAscencio No entiendo, estas iniciando en el tema de las BD? Si es asi investiga el tema y trata de comprenderlo, no preguntes cosas que no sabes directamente, es bueno siempre investigar de antemano